# Reading bmp files

Tags: c, image, bmp

I am writing a simple BMP library (just for learning purposes). So far I am able to read only 24-bit BMP files and that's because I am confused about what's happening when the bit-depth is not 24. Here's what I don't understand:

1) I know that a look-up-table (color palette) is mandatory for `bit-depth <= 8` (1,2,4 and 8) but what about 16, 24 and 32? Can they have look-up-tables?

2) Is it possible to have `BI_BITFIELDS` compression for `bit-depth <= 8`?

3) In case the compression is 0 (`BI_RGB` - no compression) the 24 bit depth is `RGB888` and the 32 bit depth is `RGBA8888` but what about 16 bit depth? Is it `RGB555` or `RGB565`? This is something that documentation of bmp doesn't mention or at least I didn't find it.

4) Is it true that normally (`BI_RGB`) we have only `RGB` (no alpha) and only in `BI_BITFIELDS` we can have `RGBA`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: It's worth saying that nobody will really get mad at you if you don't support compressed BMP or "strange" pixel formats; most programs claiming to support BMP don't support anything besides 1/2/8/24/32 bpp uncompressed data with no alpha - i.e. the "original" BMP format.

Comment: This is about the file format and not a C question,

Comment: @MatteoItalia You are definitely right, but like I said I am doing this just for learning purposes (obviously nobody would use my bmp lib :P). One thing I don't get is the 32bpp, in the documentation I see RGBAX88808 and I am wondering what's the point of using 32bpp if you waste 8bits. In the end it's the same with the 24bpp. Am I wrong?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes I know, I already read this.

Comment: Not very well I guess, all 4 of your questions are answered on that page.